# Problem on loading JQuery mock up script on workflow form CstWrkflIP.aspx

Tags: jquery, postback

I am trying to mock up the Workflow form (the URL is ~siteCollection/_layouts/15/CstWrkflIP.aspx?List={xxx}) with JQuery. I have included the script file within Master Page so that whenever the URL matching, the script will hide some fields and pre-fill some input, etc.

The script fired as expected at first load. But when I click on the "Add stage" button of Approval Workflow, all the mock up is gone. I guess it is because it triggered a postback and my script is not run again.

The "Add stage" button is the highlighted one:

[image]

I have placed this line in my script:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("workflowMockUp");
```

workflowmockup is my JQ function name.

Maybe I do it wrong. It only triggered first time page is load. When I click "Add a new stage" workflowMockUp is not triggered. How can I workaround it? I cannot modify CstWrkflIP.aspx directly.

Comment: Are you using MDS ?

Comment: @JayHell No, MDS is not enabled.

Comment: Can you paste the complete code?

Comment: I just tested this with no result, maybe you have ideas with this:
document.querySelectorAll("[role='button'] > a")[0].addEventListener("click", function() { document.querySelector('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_XmlFormControl_V1_I1_T4').innerText += "This is a test"  });

You may be stuck doing an infinite loop.

Infopath is basically a front end for XML. Could be that the button basically does a post to this XML to add changes into the file before adding an additional row in the front end. I'll see if I find anything.

Comment: If you want some code for an infinite loop I can write some for you. But it's not a clean solution.

Comment: Pardon me, but what are you even trying to accomplish? What you are looking at is an InfoPath form and you are trying to use Javascript (well, jQuery library) on it. SharePoint 2013 let's you create custom initiation forms using HTML, CSS and Javascript if you really want some customised initiation form.

Comment: Why do you think he wants a customized form? It don't think it matters whether it's infopath or not, CstWrkflIP.aspx is an out of the box built-in form.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not how it's supposed to work, but try to wrap you function call in a jQuery(document).ready() call. I've ran into issue with functions not being called sometimes, especially in IE. The document ready did help, although there are better practices.

Comment: I have tried following:     $(function() {workflowMockUp();}     already. It only trigger at first page load. It don't fire when click "add stage".

Comment: Have you wrapped that function in a document ready wrapper as well? <script>$(document).ready(function () { workflowMockUp(); } );</script>

Comment: Yes, I tried and still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Have you add any Jquery file or function in your code ?

I m asking because i have faced same issue.i found that 
share point function **_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("workflowMockUp")** Provides such inbuilt functionality same as the jquery.
There are chances of Conflict between  _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("workflowMockUp") and jQuery(document).ready().

Reference for this concept : 
**http://www.stephanrocks.com/2011/10/05/_spbodyonloadfunctionnames-in-sharepoint-vs-jquerys-document-ready/#comment-10478**

Answer (score -4):

check spell first `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("workflowMockUp")` these are correct or not

Comment: The spell is correct because the _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames do trigger workflowMockUp first time page is load. But it doesn't fire again at postback.